# if not equal to OR not equal to in R?

Tags: r

Basic question... and I know there are many similar questions to mine but none of them seem to directly answer my question.

Basically I want to create a warning message in R if none of the conditions are met... but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong!? Below is a very simple example:

```
FUNC <- function(x){
  if(x != "barChart" || x != "scatterPlot"){
  stop("x must be barChart or scatterPlot")
  }else{print("Hello")}
}

FUNC("barChart")
```

This should result in `"Hello"` but instead it's returning the warning message. I'm guessing im structuring the if-or statement incorrectly... any suggestions as to how I would write it correctly?

Comment: is the double OR the problem? - `||`

Comment: Tried it with the single or `|`... I still get the same incorrect result

Comment: Use `&&` instead of `||`.

Comment: Your logic is faulty. If `x <- "barChart"`, then `x != "scatterPlot"` is TRUE.

Comment: `if(!(x %in% c("barChart","scatterPlot")))  stop("x must be barChart or scatterPlot")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd advise you to use `stopifnot` for such assertions.

```
FUNC <- function(x){
  stopifnot("x must be barChart or scatterPlot" = x %in% c("barChart", "scatterPlot"))
  print("Hello")
}

FUNC("barChart")
#[1] "Hello"
FUNC("scatterPlot")
#[1] "Hello"
FUNC("test")
# Error in FUNC("test") : x must be barChart or scatterPlot
```

Answer (score 3):

- If x is a scatter plot, then it is not a bar chart, so `x != "barchart"` is `TRUE`.
- If x is a bar chart then it is not a scatter plot, so `x != "Scatterplot"` is `TRUE`
- If x is neither a bar chart nor a scatter plot, both conditions will be `TRUE`
- The `||` means return `TRUE` if either statement is `TRUE`
- This means `x` will always be `TRUE`

Therefore the solution is

```
if(x != "barChart" & x != "scatterPlot")
```